# File attachment support

Tags: feature-request, attachment

I'm not sure how hard this is, but it'd be great if file attachment were supported.

This would be useful for [detailed questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19417/how-do-i-implement-a-quaternion-based-camera) that take hella work to analyze, and a lot of guessing, while really a couple of steps through the debugger would actually make it a 2-5 minute problem to solve.  Having the related code files easily available would make it easier to solve this type of question.

There are a host of [file hosting services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_hosting_services) each with their own subscription plans.